# EXIF - multi-valued field for taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

For EXIF I need an image metadata field that I can use to upload multiple taxonomy values (gallery/category) for an image content type. Apart from keywords which I am using as such I need another field that will link to the gallery taxonomy - an image can appear in several galleries.

At the moment keywords seems to be the only field that EXIF uses to populate multi-valued taxonomy fields. If I add 2 values in IPTC CATEGORY say separated by commas or semi-colons (e.g. News, Sport) it creates a new combined taxonomy value of "News, Sport" in the vocabulary, not what I want.

Any suggestions? I am using EXIF on Drupal 7 - both latest versions.

*Since initially posing the question I tried using EditableViews modules in the hope it would allow me to edit the gallery entries but it would not let me edit the fields although it did display them.*